# How to watch Apple TV+ shows on a TV without the Apple TV device?

Tags: video, airplay, appletv

I was wondering whether it's possible to watch Apple TV+ shows on my LG TV?

I tried (or can try) the following:

1. My TV has a Chromecast plugged in, but it doesn't appear to be an option.
2. I searched the LG store for an Apple TV+ app, but one doesn't exist.  Apple said in the press-release that one is coming but not yet.
3. I have an XBOX, but didn't find a way to stream from iOS to it either.
4. I also have an Raspberry Pi and I found code for an [AirPlay mirroring server](https://github.com/FD-/RPiPlay), which I would have to build.  But the site recommends RPi 3 for smoothness - I only have RPi 2.  So this could possibly be an option.

Anything else I can do (short of buying Apple TV device)?

Answer (score 1):

You can watch Apple TV+ on the web at [tv.apple.com](https://tv.apple.com).  From there, you can cast it to your Chromecast to watch on the LG tv.

LG has a few tv's that currently support Apple TV+ but there's only 4 of them right now and you need to use AirPlay 2 to send the content to the tv:

- LG OLED (2019)
- LG NanoCell SM8X series (2019)
- LG NanoCell SM9X series (2019)
- LG UHD UM7X series (2019)

As more manufacturers see if this is a success or not, you can expect to see changes in support.

I would recommend signing-up for the 7-day free trial and use a web browser to cast it to your tv.  You can then decide if it's worth buying an inexpensive/used Apple TV 3rd gen to continue (or not if you don't mind using the Chromecast).

For more info on devices and shows you can visit [Apple's overview page](https://offers.appletvapp.apple).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind spending (slightly) on a new hardware, [Roku Streaming Players](https://www.roku.com/products/players) or [Amazon Fire TV Stick](https://www.amazon.com/b/?node=8521791011) are both a fantastic option.

Both of them are economically priced, easy to setup, and support official Apple TV app.